# syntax error near unexpected token 'done' when running a script

Tags: sh

So I am running the following shellscript and I receive the error syntax error near unexpected token 'done'. What is wrong with it ? What have I missed ?

```
    #!/bin/sh
    df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpf|cdrom' | awk ' {print $5 " " $6}' | while read output
do
echo $output
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
echo $usep
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}' )
if [ $usep -ge 90 ]; then 
    echo "Running out of space  \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date) : $usep%" |
        mail -s "Alert: Critical Almost out of disk space $partition $usep%"
user@mail.eu
fi
if [ $usep -ge 5 ]; then
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date) : $usep%" |
        mail -s "Alert: Warning Almost out of disk space $partition $usep%" user@mail.eu
fi
done
```

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Since a pipeline cannot end with a `|`, such lines are automatically continued.

Comment: Your script looks fine; how are you running it? On what system? With which shell? ... The question was originally tagged as `python`, are you using Python to run a shell script? This is obviously wrong...

Comment: Cannot reproduce, although you should quote your parameter expansions inside `[...]`, and you may want to verify that those values are, in fact, integers.

Comment: Are you running on Cygwin? What does `file name-of-script` print?

Answer (score 1):

I copy-pasted your script and tested it under Cygwin.

I get the syntax error using Windows end-of-line (CRLF) but the script works fine if converted to Unix EOL (LF)